# Getting the width of child element pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Html:

```
<div class="project-box">
 <img src="img/ifix.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
   <div class="hover-box">
     <h2>TITLE</h2>
     <p>Description of title</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

javascipt:

```
window.onload = function(){

var project = document.getElementsByClassName('project-box');
img = project.getElementsByTagName('img');
  alert(img.clientWidth); 
};
```

I'm trying to get the img width and eventually the img height using pure JavaScript I know this is a lot easier with jQuery but I want to do it using only JavaScript.
EDIT:
I realized I was not specifying the array for the img and project

working js:

```
window.onload = function(){

var project = document.getElementsByClassName('project-box');
img = project[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
 alert(img[0].offsetWidth);
};
```

Comment: Try `img.clientWidth`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of objects, so you need to access the actual element by its index then call its methods/properties

```
window.onload = function () {
    var project = document.getElementsByClassName('project-box')[0];
    var img = project.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    alert(img.clientWidth);
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kC34H/)

Comment: thank you I relized this right before reading your answer so I did it a bit different but still works I gave you the check since its still the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe project.getElementsByTagName('img'); is returning an array, even if it only has one object.

Try something like

```
window.onload = function(){

var project = document.getElementsByClassName('project-box');
img = project.getElementsByTagName('img');
  alert(img.pop().width); //This should remove the element from the array and then call width
};
```

Comment: there are several of the project-box and img i tried adding img[0].width but still no result

Comment: Oh! I just realized you aren't declaring the variable img.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
alert(img.clientWidth);
```

Comment: Sorry, i realized that img is an array of elements, it must be img[0].clientWidth

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because .getElementsByClassName() and .getElementsByTagName() both wrap elements inside an [object HTMLContainer], you need to select the first element from each of these objects.

This code should work:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var project = document.getElementsByClassName('project-box');
            img = project[0].getElementsByTagName('img');

    console.log(img[0].clientWidth);
};
```